# Changing the location of url angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had a common button in all the pages. Onclick of the button I need to open the html page with the slideToggle animation. Again on click of the same button the page should be in the same location path

Now what is happening is navigation to the page is properly happening on the first click on second click the page it is not launching corresponding page it is just redirecting to main.html page.

```
<button ng-click="goTo(nextPage)">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
 app.when('/screen2', {
                controller: 'abc',
                templateUrl: "sub.html"
            })
```

Controller:

```
$scope.nextPage = 'screen2';
        $scope.goTo = function (page) {
            $location.path('/' + page);
            $scope.nextPage = (page === 'screen2') ? '' : 'screen2';
        };
```

Is there any better way to achieve and to store the previous URL Path.

Comment: Any way of achieving this and storing the orevioys URL would be better, since you neither achieve what you want, nor store the previous URL.

Comment: I read the question again. It's not even clear **what** you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I know to go to the previous page it to use history.back() which will go back to the previous page.

As for no being able click on the button again that would be because your're essentially doing this

```
if (page === 'screen2'){
      return '';
   }else{
      return 'screen2';
  }
```

On the second click because the url is already screen2 it will return nothing which will then send you to the main.html page and that is the default route.

Hope this helps